# rmarkdown toc missing when rendering bookdown::html_document2

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

When I `knit` the following `test.Rmd` file:

```
---
title: "test"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    toc: true
    toc_float: TRUE
    code_folding: show
---


# heading 1

# heading 2
```

It produces a `toc`:

[image]

But when I render it using:

```
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_format = "html_document2")
```

The `toc` is missing:

[image]

Does anyone know how to include `toc` when rendering with `bookdown::html_document2`?

thanks

Comment: You should use `output_format = 'bookdown::html_document2'` instead of `output_format = 'html_document2'`. Please see the corrected answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output format name should be exactly what you specified in the YAML metadata, i.e.,

```r
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_format = 'bookdown::html_document2')
```

instead of

```r
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', output_format = 'html_document2')
```

---

Alternatively (not recommended), you can call the output format function with options:

```r
rmarkdown::render(
  'test.Rmd', 
  output_format = bookdown::html_document2( 
    list(toc = TRUE, toc_float = TRUE
  )
)
```

or

```r
rmarkdown::render(
  'test.Rmd', 
  output_format = 'bookdown::html_document2',
  output_options = list(toc = TRUE, toc_float = TRUE)
)
```

These alternative methods are unnecessarily more complicated, and also make the document less reproducible (not making use of options specified inside the document), so you are recommended to just use `output_format = 'bookdown::html_document2'` and specify output format options in the Rmd document.

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie for the clarifications and the edit.